# Combine legend icon matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am tying to display a plot and it's confidence interval with a single icon in the legend using matplotlib.
In the past I use to write:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
curve = ax1.plot(...)
curve_fil = ax.fill_between(...)
fig.legend([(curve[0], curve_fill[0])], ["label here"], ...)
```

Which would work, and allow me to produce plots like:
[image]

However now I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'PolyCollection' object is not subscriptable
```

If I remove the `[0]` and just provide the plot as argument, I get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_artists'
```

And if I try to create custom patches like:

```
patch = mpatches.Patch(color='r')
fig.legend([(curve[0], patch)], ["label here"])
```

Then I get:

```
TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not subscriptable
```

What does this all mean? I am starting to pull the hair off of my head on this one...
I know similar questions have already been posted but since all the suggestions that have been tagged as valid answers didn't work for me I dicedid to post this one.

Comment: `fig.legend([(curve[0], curve_fil)], ["label here"])` seems to work

Comment: You are right! How did it get passed me? I guess I was tired today. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Posting for my likely future reference, and to help out anybody else who wants to do the same thing:

```py
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], linestyle = "dashed", marker = "o", color='#00ff3f', label = '1 Hz Data, Interpolation'), Line2D([0], [0], linestyle = "dashed", marker = "o", color='#35b6ff', label = '10 Hz Data, Interpolation'), Line2D([0], [0], linestyle = "dashed", marker = "o", color='#ff469c', label = '10 Hz Data, Interpolation')]
ax.legend(handles = legend_elements)
```

[image: Screenshot of Legend Produced]

[Matplotlib Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html)

Comment: I should note that the third should read `100 Hz Data, Interpolation`, but that's my typo and not really relevant to the solution.